# : error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [40]'

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am reading a book and It told me to open a empty WIN32 project.  I created source file called main.cpp and put it in the source folder (This is the only file I have in my project). In that file put the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                  LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Motoko kusangai has hacked your system!", "Public Security Section 9", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
}
```

And run it. But I get the following error:

```
1>c:\users\numerical25\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\begin\begin\main.cpp(6) : error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [40]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\numerical25\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Begin\Begin\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Begin - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a wide string in this case because you are compiling for unicode.  Try prefixing all of your string constants with L.

```
MessageBox(
  NULL, 
  L"Motoko kusangai has hacked your system!", 
  L"Public Security Section 9", 
  MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
```

Comment: Your right! Thanks alot. And I thought I knew alot about programming. c++ is a whole new ball game. I am unformiluar with compiling for unicode. do you know any good resources that explains what these are ?? And why did the books compiler not need it and I did. they too are using MSV. Not sure what version but the interface look completely identical.

Comment: haha, never mind, lil later on it explain that I will get a error :P. I hate it when books do that.

Answer (score 4):

Petzold's classic Programming Windows starts off with a great chapter on Unicode that I'd recommend reading. If you are going to be doing any Win32 UI work I'd get a copy of his book. Given how out of favor Win32 is these days you can pick up used copies of the most recent 5th edition for less than $20. Unlike most technical authors Charles has a very conversational style and uses strong story telling techniques to make his books very readable despite their length (his Programming Windows with C# was similarly good).

It's good practice these days to use unicode strings but if you really don't want them you can go into the **project properties** in VS and change the Character Set to "**Use Multi-Byte Character Set**", which will essentially get you the regular 8 bit ASCII you are probably used to.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                  LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Motoko kusangai has hacked your system!"), _T("Public Security Section 9"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
}
```

Each time you get this error for some static text, enclose the static text within _T() tags.

Edit: [MS Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc500362.aspx)

Comment: oh.. strange, haven't used C++ in a while, but was sure it was _T, L"" must of worked then :) Cheers for replying tho

Comment: For 32-bit compilation, you'd be right. For 64-bit, MS has made wide strings the default, without defining _UNICODE, which means `_T` and `TEXT` don't work (under these circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error and changing to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" worked for me. I am using Visual Studio 2012.